# How do you read a value returned by a method in smartcontract using web3j?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3-java

I'm using [web3j](https://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/) in Android studio to interact with smartcontracts.

In my SmartContract i've 2 functions `getName()` and `getAge()` and i'm setting age and name in constructor as below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Identify {

    string name;
    uint age;

    constructor() public {
        name = "Shoaib Khalid";
        age = 22;
    }

    function getName() view public returns(string memory){
        return name;
    }


    function getAge() view public returns(uint){
        return age;
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to read the value returned by both functions. After deploying the smartcontract correctly, following is the method I'm trying to read the value returned by `getName()` function.

```
  val identityContract = Identity_sol_Identify.load(
            deployedContractAddress,
            web3j,
            getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(),
            DefaultGasProvider.GAS_PRICE,
            DefaultGasProvider.GAS_LIMIT
        )
  Log.d(TAG, "counter Result:  ${identityContract.name.sendAsync().get()}")
```

Instead of getting the value `Shoaib Khalid` which I set in the constructor I'm getting a `TranscriptReciept` object the output screenshoot is attached below.
[image]

**So I want to know can you read the exact value returned by the function `getName()` in smartcontract using web3j?**

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Web3j documentation:

> Transactional calls do not return any values, regardless of the return type specified on the method. Hence, for all transactional
> methods the Transaction Receipt associated with the transaction is
> returned [[1]](https://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/smart_contracts/interacting_with_smart_contract/#invoking-transactions-and-events)
> ...
>
> The transaction receipt is useful for two reasons:
>
> It provides details of the mined block that the transaction resides in Solidity events that are called will be logged as part of
> the transaction, which can then be extracted.

You are getting the transaction receipt. In order to query the values from your state variables you should refer to the section [Querying the state of a smart contract](https://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/transactions/transactions_and_smart_contracts/#querying-the-state-of-a-smart-contract) and do something like this:

```
Function function = new Function<>(
             "getName", // This is the name of the solidity function in your smart contract
             Collections.emptyList(),  // Solidity Types in smart contract functions, no input in the function so we set this to empty
             Arrays.asList(new TypeReference<Utf8String>() {})); // result will be a string

String encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthCall response = web3j.ethCall(
             Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(contractAddress, encodedFunction),
             DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
             .sendAsync().get();

  Iterator<Type> it = someType.iterator();
                Type result = someType.get(0);
                String a = result.toString();
                Log.d("Name: ", a);
```